# rsync command deletion error "IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion"

Tags: permissions, rsync

I use rsync command to take backup of files from one of my ubuntu server to another ubuntu machine.
Backup server trigger a script that use rysnc command.
Here is the command I use

> rsync -rltvh --partial --stats --exclude=.beagle/ --exclude=.* --delete-after root@live_server:/home/ /home/live_server_backup/home >> /tmp/logfile.log 2>&1

live_server is ssh-able without password. So it works. Now problem is with

> --delete-after option

After all file synced .At the end I can see deletion procedure skipped.logfile error is like

> IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion

When i tried to find log there were some error while file sync

> rsync: send_files failed to open "/home/xyz/Desktop/PPT_session_1_context.pdf": Permission denied (13)

So my understanding is as rsync could not read all the files from target for safety reason it is skipping the file deletion.

Is there any way to make --delete-after work even if there is some permission error?
I do not want to use force deletion as it will be dangerous in some situation.

Comment: Pssst again... You really should.

Comment: @ArmelLarcier Sorry but what does it mean "Pssst again"? you really should what?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Additional note about this issue:

`vanished file` should not trigger the condition `IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion`, but this often happens when you are creating a backup of a live system.

This is covered by rsync bug #7809 (https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7809) and should be solved in the upcoming release 3.1.0.

In the meantime use:

```
--ignore-errors         delete even if there are I/O errors
```

Answer (score 26):

From the rsync man page:

```
--ignore-errors         delete even if there are I/O errors
```

That will address your problem.

Comment: No - it will not address the problem in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an exclusion file to make `rsync` ignore the files that it can't read.  The list can be generated with `find . -exec test -r '{}'` in the source directory and then massaged into the exclusion file format `rsync` wants.

Comment: actually my source directory is quite large (10-12GB). So each time finding files (having no read permission) will not be efficient way. what do u say?

Comment: Run it once to build the exclusion list and don't run it again unless a whole bunch of new unreadable files are added.  rsync is doing the same tree traversal, so it shouldn't be that bad, anyway.

Comment: Yes. But that's what my scenario is like. Everyday source directory may introduce such files. and I need to backup the new files into backup machine.

Comment: Is there a working solution to this? I also use rsync for backups from a live system and when there is a I/O Error on the reading machine, the files get deleted on the target machine, which SHOULD NOT HAPPEN!

Answer (score 0):

For me above IO errors, you see permission denied. Didn't notice at first, but I had to make sure the directory I was reading from was readable as the user I was trying to rsync from.

So probably mostly permission issues these days.
chown the live server appropriately and should work.