# WSL: rsync not deleting files in destination when absent from source

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rsync, mirroring, ownership

This is using WSL on a W10 machine.

I'm trying to mirror one drive to another.

The command I'm using looks like this:

```
root@M17A:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32# rsync -rtivlHu --delete --exclude "Backups" "/mnt/f/" "/mnt/h/"
```

(NB I've also tried with `delete-before`)

The problem I get is that *sometimes* a file present in the destination but not in the source doesn't get deleted. Such a file can be in the H drive root directory (in which case it is NEVER deleted), or buried deep in a directory structure, where it may or may not end up being deleted.

I see this kind of thing at the start of the output:

> ```
> root@M17A:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32# rsync -rtivlHu --delete --exclude "Backups" "/mnt/f/" "/mnt/h/"
> sending incremental file list
> rsync: opendir "/mnt/f/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-3556251925-1847326050-1130181678-1001" failed: Permission denied (13)
> rsync: failed to set times on "/mnt/h/.": Invalid argument (22)
> IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
> ./
> temp.tmp
> ...
> ```

The `rsync: opendir` line appears to concern a recycling directory and is not particularly relevant. And it doesn't matter if the recycle bins end up not mirrored. It's just that this adds to the difficulties in trying to analyse what's going wrong.

Note the line "IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion".

I have no difficulties manually copying to and deleting files from the H: drive.

Could this be something to do with W10 ownership/permissions? I have to confess that I don't understand this side of W10 at all well, and when I tried to learn about it I ended up having to go for a long sleep in a darkened room, overwhelmed by horror and mental fatigue.

Comment: Do you actually want to include the F: drive's deleted files? It requires special privileges depending on how the drive is mounted. If not, then you can continue with the file deletion using `--ignore-errors` (delete even if there are I/O errors) https://superuser.com/a/613144/673426 or just `--exclude '$RECYCLE.BIN'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IO error is failing safe and disabling the action of `--delete`. Here's what the documentation (`man rsync`) has to say on the matter:

> If  the  sending side detects any I/O errors, then the deletion of any files at the destination will be automatically disabled. This is to prevent temporary filesystem failures (such as  NFS errors)  on  the sending side from causing a massive deletion of files on the destination. You can override this with the `--ignore-errors` option.

However, simply adding `--ignore-errors` will prevent `rsync` from bailing on other unexpected errors; it's not the straightforward drop-in you might think it should be.

I'd recommend omitting the Recycle Bin from your copy and avoiding the use of `--ignore-errors`:

```
rsync -auH -iv --delete --exclude 'Backups/' --exclude '/$RECYCLE.BIN/' /mnt/f/ /mnt/h/
```

If `Backups` is actually only `/mnt/f/Backups` then you should use `/Backups/` to omit just the top-level `Backups` directory. If there are unwanted `Backups` directories scattered through the source tree (i.e. at various points under `/mnt/f`) then your current exclusion pattern without a leading `/` is correct.